# when choosing FILTER (Is NULL or Is Empty) on DATE column Field in KENDO Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

When I was choosing date column field in kendo grid after applying a filter on that column (is null), the filter causes the following exception:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value,
>   Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.FilterDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateValueExpression(Type
>   targetType, Object value, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.FilterDescriptorExpressionBuilder.CreateBodyExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.FilterDescriptorCollectionExpressionBuilder.CreateBodyExpression()
>   at Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Where(IQueryable source,
>   IEnumerable`1 filterDescriptors)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState,
>   Func`2 selector)    at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining an operator on the column and setting the type?

```
column.Bound(c => c.Date).Filterable(f => f.Operators(o => o.ForDate(e => e.Clear().IsNull("Is Null"))));
```

And set the filter mode on the grid:

```
.Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
```

i am set the .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu)) also not working isnull and isempty filter in kendo grid.